# Protext 64-bit executables for Windows

Tags: windows, distributions, protext

I'm on Windows 7 Enterprise 64bit. Are there 64-bit executables for Windows? I'm using the proTeXt TeX distribution: http://www.tug.org/protext/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Christian Schenk wrote on the miktex mailing list:

```
MiKTeX 2.9 is 32-bit. The 64-bit packages are for testing purposes only. 
I am not planning to release a 64-bit MiKTeX 2.9.
```

None of the earlier versions of miktex even mentioned 64-bit apps, and protext is definitely based on an earlier version (although I do not know which one) so: *No*.